# Is there any way to import a block that itself contains blocks with Jinja2?

Tags: flask, jinja2

Currently, the furthest I've gotten is taking the main blocks of my HTML page and creating two separate html files in a directory, `extra-scripts.html` and `page-body.html`. In two files, I have the exact same following code:

```
{% block page_body %}
{% include 'site/order/page-body.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_scripts %}
{% include 'site/order/extra-scripts.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Is there any way to create one html file that includes both of these blocks instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a base layout that you can inherit in all your other jinja files.
For example if you created a base layout named "layout.html"

You can use that layout in all your other templates such as:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    stuff here
{% endblock %}
```

documentation link -> https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/templateinheritance/

Comment: Ah this is helpful. I'm actually already inheriting once on both of these pages from a more general template. So would I then create a layer below that general template for these two pages and have each page inherit from that middle layer?

Comment: Yes absolutely! If your implementation requires this complexity then that seems to be the way that it should be implemented.

Comment: Did this answer help you?